# multiple query concat

Tags: mysql, group-concat, concatenation

hi i have been researching and having issues with a mysql query.
i have a table called "friends" which has the columns: id, user1, and user2.
i am trying to create a query where i can get 1 record resulting with a concatenation of all users from the user1 column and all users from the user2 column that relate to a specific user in order to get a result that has all of that users friends.  for example, the table "friends" may contain:

```
****friends****
id   user1   user2
0     33       1
1     33       2
2     34       25
3     3        33
4     27       33
```

the result i want is a record named "friendships" with the data being a single string containing "1,2,3,27" since those are all the user ids that user 33 is friends with. i am able to run :

```
SELECT (CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(user2) AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)) as friendships from friends where user1 =33
```

which will return "1,2" and i can reverse it in a separate query to get "3,27",however, i am trying to get the result in one query if possible! all help is appreciated :)

Comment: Write the two queries and use UNION: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Comment: i went ahead and tried the union method, the results are correct, however, i am still having an issue concatenating them into one result.  with the union im doing <pre> select user1 from friends where user2 = 33 
union
select user2 from friends where user1 = 33</pre> but it isn't in one comma separated result

Comment: Why the casting of group_concat? It already returns a string which would be treated as char/varchar/text by client software.

Comment: if i don't cast it, then the results are <33312c33 352c3336 2c333432 2c32372c 32382c32 392c3330 2c33322c 3338>

Comment: The union result is a bunch of SQL rows. I am guessing the `CAST(GROUP_CONCAT())` business would convert that into a comma-separated string for you. Something like `SELECT (CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(x) AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)) FROM (select user1 x from friends where user2 = 33 union select user2 x from friends where user1 = 33)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work if I understand you question correctly

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(a.friendships, b.friendships) as x from (
    (SELECT (CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(user2) AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)) as friendships from friends where user1 = 33) as a,
    (SELECT (CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(user1) AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)) as friendships from friends where user2 = 33) as b
)
```

Comment: thanks, this answer works, and so does ypercubes answer, which do you think is a better performing option? i tried running both of them over and over again but the times vary widely

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(u) AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) AS friendships 
FROM
  ( SELECT user2 AS u
    FROM friends 
    WHERE user1 = 33
  UNION ALL
    SELECT user1
    FROM friends 
    WHERE user2 = 33
  ) AS tmp
```